# PHP Calling a method multiple times;

Tags: php

I am trying to understand why calling a method multiple times inside another method doesn't work as it should this the code:

```
<?php
Class A {
    private $m;
    function __construct($m){
        $this->m = $m;
    }

    function _add(){
        return ($this->m)+1;
    }

    function add($v) {
        for ($i = 1; $i < $v; $i++){
            $k = $this->_add();
        }
        return new A($k);
    }

    function get(){
        return $this->m;
    }
}

$c = new A(2);

echo $c->add(5)->get();
?>
```

The answer I got is 3=(2+1) 2 from initialization and 1 from only once adding, but I expect getting 2+4=6.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to chain calls like that the functions in the chain have to return a reference to the object itself

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `for` loop will run one fewer times that you're expecting as well - you probably want to `<=` comparison.

Comment: `$k = $this->_add();` doesn’t increment $k or $this->m, so no matter how many times you loop you end up adding one.

Comment: The `$k` variable gets a new value with each iteration of the `for` loop, which means that you set its value to `$this->m+1 == 2 + 1 == 3` a number of 4 times, but its final final is still just `3`.

Comment: **Why** do you expect that result? What have you tried to check for the difference?

Answer (score 1):

First if you want to chain method calls the intermediary methods have to return the object and not a calculated value, so `add()` in this case, so accumulate the summation in the object property rather than returning it.

Second the for loop need to start at 0 not 1

```
Class A {
    private $m;
    function __construct($m){
        $this->m = $m;
    }

    function _add(){
        return ($this->m)+1;
    }

    function add($v) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $v; $i++){
            $this->m = $this->_add();
        }
        return $this;
    }

    function get(){
        return $this->m;
    }
}

$c = new A(2);
echo $c->add(5)->get();
```

RESULT

```
7
```

Comment: It's totally fine to return a new value/object if the style you're after is immutable, so returning `$this` is not a requirement, just a choice of style (with deep implications).

Comment: I dont think I said it was a requirement in all cases. However is it not a requirement if I want to chain an objects method calls? @IonuțG.Stan

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Even if one wants to chain method calls on objects _of the same class_, they can still be different objects produced using `new` by each method call.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Err, yes. I think I understand, well no I am afraid I dont :) Having a senior day :) :)

Comment: No worries :) All I wanted to say is that the choice between returning `$this` or `new A` depends on whether one wants to mutate the object in place or create copies of it, but both approaches afford method chains.

Comment: Ahh @IonuțG.Stan Thanks for the clarification. Sorry I am being a bit dim today

Answer (score 0):

`$c = new A(2);` initializes new object with the `$m` field set to 2

Then method `add` called with parameter 5 calls `_add()` 4 times:

```
        for ($i = 1; $i < $v; $i++){
            $k = $this->_add();
        }
```

method `_add()` just returns value of `$m` increased by 1:

```
    function _add(){
        return ($this->m)+1;
    }
```

therefore `$k` in `add` equals to 2+1 = 3.

Method `add` returns this value enclosed in a new object.

Probably you want to rewrite method `add` like this

```
    function _add(){
        return ++($this->m);
    }
```

for the increased value to be stored in `$m`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from being a solution to the problem, I would be more inclined to make the code more readable and obvious to anyone that maintains it.

```
$c->add(5)
echo $c->get();
```